# Rails 3 Unknown Action even though its define in my routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have an app that I am working on that directs users to a "bundle" page when purchasing one product so that they have the opportunity to add another product to "bundle" their purchase for a discount.

Here is my routes:

```
resources :orders, :path_names => { :new => 'checkout' }
match "/orders/bundle" => "orders#bundle", :as => 'bundle_order'
match "/orders/add_product" => "orders#add_product", :as => 'add_product'
```

Here is my Controller#Action

```
def bundle
op_client = Client.find_by_name(opposite_client(current_client))
@product = Product.find_by_client_id_and_type_and_status(op_client.id, "subscription", "Active")

respond_with @product
end
```

For some reason when I `redirect_to` this method, I receive this error:

```
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for OrdersController
```

I don't have a show method in my OrdersController cause I don't need it. Why would I be seeing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error could be caused by two diferent things.

first:

are you using something like: `<%= link_to @order_object %>` ?? if you are, this is the problem.

second:

on `routes.rb` change this line:

```
resources :orders, :path_names => { :new => 'checkout' }
```

to

```
resources :orders, :path_names => { :new => 'checkout' }, :except => [:show]
```

this should work. if not, please give more details about the code you are using to do the `redirect_to`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually would up rewriting some of the routes based on client requests.